# button do not get invisible on click of row in listview

Tags: android, listview, button

I want when i click on listview row a button should get visible and when i again click on same row that button should disappear. On first click button is appearing but again on clicking it is not getting invisible. in log i can see "is not visible" but not the other one.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
  System.out.println("I clicked row item");
        Button  button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        if(!shouldVisible)//IF IT IS invISIBLE
        {
            System.out.println("value is"+shouldVisible);
        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shouldVisible = false;
        }
        else //IF IT IS NOT inVISIBLE
        {
            System.out.println(shouldVisible);
            button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        shouldVisible = true;
        }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "YOU CLICKED ITEM "+pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to create intilize button1 in getView(). like Button button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

Comment: When clicking you initialize the button1 so you may Initialize the button1 outside `lv.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: when i am again clicking on row then it is not even entering onItemClick method. I applied log then observe this

Comment: @Loren can you post the new code  ;

Comment: @Vasilisfoo USING THIS CODE I CAN ONLY FIND value is false in logs

Comment: You should initialise the button outside the onitemclick

Comment: You are using my method in a wrong way
just replace
shouldVisible = false;

with shouldVisible = true;
and vice versa 
shouldVisible = true;
with
shouldVisible = false;

Comment: @Loren Again you initialize the button1 inside on Item click so each time you press the row the button is being initilized , also you don't initialize the _shouldVisible_ so it goes to the _Else_ at first time

Comment: @Vasilisfoo if i initialise it outside from where i will get view reference for v.findViewById(R.id.button1)

Comment: see my edited answer @Loren

Comment: @HanishSharma same problem persist

Comment: @Loren i have made edition in your question as well

Comment: @Loren I prefer your previous implementation about the _if_,  _else_ statements

Comment: @HanishSharma with what value sholud i initialise the variable true/false

Comment: false,
buy the way it is false by default. :-)

Comment: @HanishSharma but still the problem persist

Answer (score 1):

Take a boolean
Lets take

```
private boolean shouldVisible;
```

in your onitemclick
you can do the following thing

```
if(!shouldVisible)
{
yourButton.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
shouldVisible = true;
}
else
{
yourButton.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
shouldVisible = false;
}
```

and

```
Button button1;
```

use this outside

and use this

```
button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

inside of onitemclick

Comment: not working.. :( same it is becoming visible but not getting invisible

Comment: button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

use this outside

Comment: Why are using 
   button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
in your onitemclick ??

Comment: Is your button is in the item of listview??
if yes then use this logic in you adapter class

Comment: my button is in item of listview which is separate class from the class where I have declared my list.

Comment: in the if part 
set 
shouldVisible = true;
instead of
shouldVisible = false;
and same 
in the else part 
use 
shouldVisible = false;
instead of 
shouldVisible = true;

Comment: i have changed now in log only i can see my first log and value is false. on the second click its not showing that it has entered onItemClick.

Comment: Button  button1;
done it out side rest use my above logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89148/discussion-between-loren-and-hanish-sharma).

Comment: My chat is not working buddy beacuse of the proxy ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
button1.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
```

From [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

Comment: its not even entering in that method braces